# What is a service in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have searched a lot to understand what is a service and why and when should we use them? What is the best way to create a service? What is its difference with plugin?

I have read resources from [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html) and [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is a service?**

A 'service' is *any information* in your application (often a PHP object instance) that is registered with the service manager.

The service manager acts as a central repository for all your classes; abstracting their creation using 'service factories'. This will allow the information to be requested in any area of the application using one or more 'service names'.

The terminology used is not specific to ZF2 but rather the [Service Locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) and [Dependancy Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) design patterns.

**Why use a service?**

- Registering a service name or alias

You remove the need to reference/create a object by its class name; instead you request it by it's *service name*. If any any point my application's requirements for `FooService` were to be different I could swap the default `FooServiceFactory` for a new, perhaps very different service by simply updating the factory that is registered to that name.

- Abstracting the creation of objects, [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming))

There is only one location where your class are created (a service factory). Consider a class that has many constructor arguments, if you were to add an additional argument it would mean finding all instances where you have created the object using `new` and adding the new argument.

- Dependency Injection

In complex applications the arguments needed to create a service can themselves be complex. We would call these *dependencies*. We can model these dependencies as services themselves and use the service manager to request and 'inject' them into the required service.

Consider an `EmailService`, it has many complex dependencies, all of them can be requested from the service manager, each having their own factories.

Example email service factory:

```
class EmailServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return new EmailService(
            $serviceLocator->get('Email\Config\EmailConfig'),
            $serviceLocator->get('Email\Entity\Repository\EmailRepository'),
            $serviceLocator->get('Message\Entity\Repository\MessageStatusRepository'),
            $serviceLocator->get('Email\Service\EmailTransportService'),
            $serviceLocator->get('Email\Service\EmailTemplateService')
        );
    }
}
```

**ZF2**

- Factories

There are many different ways you can register your service with the service locator (essentially different factories). Which 'type' of factory you use will normally depend on the service's dependencies. These are explained in detail in the [documentation](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.services.html#servicemanager).

- Plugin Managers

> Plugin managers, which are specialized service managers used to manage objects that are of a related type, such as view helpers, controller plugins, controllers, etc.

The framework logically separates different types of services, although fundamentally they are all created by the service manager, it makes considerably easier to manage and create similar service with their own service manager. Some examples include the `FormElementManager`, `ControllerPluginManager` and `ViewHelperPluginManager`.

Answer (score 0):

A service can be any object that will be instanciated by a service locator.

Here are common services :

- Controllers
- Controllers plugins
- View helpers

If you're using [Zend\Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html) you may also have a UserTableGateway service, to manage your users persistence. Then you will have to provide a factory to the service locator that will instanciate the class and provide the dependencies (table name, adapter, etc).